# Crystal Report Formula

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

Before I start, I am a beginner when writing formulas.

I am writing a field formula in Crystal Report that is basically:

FIELD-1000000

I want the field to be subtracted by 1000000 UNLESS the field is 0

How do I add the "unless the field is 0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You formula should look like

```
if {FIELD} <> 0 then {FIELD}-1000000
```

If you need to calculate something else (for example then value *2) on that specific occasion then the formula is like

```
if {FIELD} <> 0 then {FIELD}-1000000
else {FIELD}*2
```

Explanation : `<> 0` in CR means any other value than 0

Hope it helps

Comment: @BillReilly No problem. If it solved your problem then accept answer. :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if not equal to for numeric value, go by using '<>'. For e.g.

```
if(field<>0) then your logic
```